# Redux - Fetch data, but render in another component

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I'm currently fetching data in Component1, then dispatching an action to update the store with the response. The data can be seen in Component2 in `this.props`, but how can I render it when the response is returned? I need a way to reload the component when the data comes back.

Initially I had a series of functions run in `componentDidMount` but those are all executed before the data is returned to the Redux store from Component1. Is there some sort of `async/await` style between components?

```
class Component1 extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.retrieveData()
    }

    retrieveData = async () => {
        let res = await axios.get('url')
        updateParam(res.data) // Redux action creator
    }
}
```

```
class Component2 extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
       this.sortData()
    }

    sortData = props => {
        const { param } = this.props
        let result = param.sort((a,b) => a - b)
    }
}

mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { param: state.param }
}

connect(mapStateToProps)(Component2)
```

In Component2, this.props is undefined initially because the data has not yet returned. By the time it is returned, the component will not rerender despite `this.props` being populated with data.

Comment: Render the component when the data is ready https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: Components rerender when state or props update. If a new prop object is received by Component2 then it should rerender. If you do something slightly silly like store props into local component state then you'll need to utilize `componentDidUpdate` or an `useEffect` with appropriate dependency to update local state. Please update your question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example for more help or better assistance.

Comment: I've updated the question with some code.

Comment: "...but the view is always one render behind." What are you doing with the `result` from the sortData function?

Comment: @DrewReese very simple mapping in JSX in render.

Comment: Yes, but *how* does `result` in `sortData` get to the `render` function? This feels related to the "something slightly silly" bit of my earlier comment.

Comment: `appointmentDates` should really be a local component state object, then when you update it in a lifecycle function react will correctly rerender and you won't need to force anything. ***OR*** since you aren't doing anything other than computing formatted data to render, `Appointments` should just call `setAppointmentDates` and `sortAppointmentsByDate` in the render function.

Comment: Moving the functions to render fixed it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `updateParam` action creator is correctly wrapped in call to `dispatch` in `mapDispatchToProps` in the `connect` HOC ***AND*** properly accessed from props in `Component1`, then I suggest checking/comparing props with previous props in `componentDidUpdate` and calling `sortData` if specifically the `param` prop value updated.

```
class Component2 extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
       this.sortData()
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
      const { param } = this.props;
      if (prevProps.param !== param) { // <-- if param prop updated, sort
        this.sortData();
      }
    }

    sortData = () => {
        const { param } = this.props
        let result = param.sort((a, b) => a - b));
        // do something with result
    }
}

mapStateToProps = state => ({
  param: state.param,
});

connect(mapStateToProps)(Component2);
```

## EDIT

Given component code from repository

```
let appointmentDates: object = {};
class Appointments extends React.Component<ApptProps> {
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps: any) {
        if (prevProps.apptList !== this.props.apptList) {
            appointmentDates = {};
            this.setAppointmentDates();
            this.sortAppointmentsByDate();
            this.forceUpdate();
        }
    }

    setAppointmentDates = () => {
        const { date } = this.props;
        for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            const d = new Date(
                new Date(date).setDate(new Date(date).getDate() + i)
            );
            let month = new Date(d).toLocaleString("default", {
                month: "long"
            });
            let dateOfMonth = new Date(d).getDate();
            let dayOfWeek = new Date(d).toLocaleString("default", {
                weekday: "short"
            });
            // @ts-ignore
            appointmentDates[dayOfWeek + ". " + month + " " + dateOfMonth] = [];
        }
    };

    sortAppointmentsByDate = () => {
        const { apptList } = this.props;
        let dates: string[] = [];
        dates = Object.keys(appointmentDates);
        apptList.map((appt: AppointmentQuery) => {
            return dates.map(date => {
                if (
                    new Date(appt.appointmentTime).getDate().toString() ===
                    // @ts-ignore
                    date.match(/\d+/)[0]
                ) {
                    // @ts-ignore
                    appointmentDates[date].push(appt);
                }
                return null;
            });
        });
    };

    render() {
        let list: any = appointmentDates;

        return (
            <section id="appointmentContainer">
                {Object.keys(appointmentDates).map(date => {
                    return (
                        <div className="appointmentDateColumn" key={date}>
                            <span className="appointmentDate">{date}</span>
                            {list[date].map(
                                (apptInfo: AppointmentQuery, i: number) => {
                                    return (
                                        <AppointmentCard
                                            key={i}
                                            apptInfo={apptInfo}
                                        />
                                    );
                                }
                            )}
                        </div>
                    );
                })}
            </section>
        );
    }
}
```

`appointmentDates` should really be a local component state object, then when you update it in a lifecycle function react will correctly rerender and you won't need to force anything. ***OR*** since you aren't doing anything other than computing formatted data to render, `Appointments` should just call `setAppointmentDates` and `sortAppointmentsByDate` in the render function.

Comment: Similar to StackQ's answer, I have to add `this.forceUpdate` at the end of `componentDidUpdate` for this to work correctly. I'm comparing a large object in props. Even if I were to compare each property individually, some are initialized as `[ ]` and `[ ] === [ ]` is false. This would lead `componentDidUpdate` to execute unintentionally.

Comment: @SimonWong Yes, very similar. I didn't see theirs until after I answered and the page refreshed. Perhaps you can update your question to include *complete* component code and share what the prop shape is that you're comparing. The pattern of our answers is correct but it seems the issue is getting the conditional test correct.